# capture only one image in ALPR

Tags: opencv

I'm working on Licesnse Plate Recognition,
everything is setup and works correctly on a single image
but there's a problem when I test it on the camera:
as long as the camera can see the plate, it keeps capturing from plate, but one image is fine.

EDITED:
for example for just one car, I've got 20 plate images from that car,
keeping the first image and deleteing the rest of them(in this case 19 images) I think it's not a good solution, because for this case it's 20 images, what if captured  images is more or less than 20

what is the solution for this?

thanks

Comment: what does this mean: "it keeps capturing from plate"??

Comment: As Micka stated, please try to explain what you mean with this sentence: "as long as the camera can see the plate, it keeps capturing from plate, but one image is fine.".

Do you want to break the capture once a successful recognition is made?

Comment: I've edited my post